# Use LINQ to remove the first column in a DatagGridView for each control in a ControlCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

So, the non-LINQ way would be something like this:

```
foreach(Control cont in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (cont is DataGridView)
    {
        var grid = cont as DataGridView;
        grid.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

I have tried doing this in Linq. Its more for the learning experience than specifically doing it the best way. Anyway this is where I am at so far, but it does not work obviously.

```
panel1.Controls = panel1.Controls
                        .AsParallel()
                        .OfType<DataGridView>()
                        .Select(grid => grid.Columns
                                            .OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                            .Skip(1));
```

So what can be done to amend the linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution uses `AsParallel()` for no clear reason, and fails to actually remove a column.

LINQ is really for querying things, not modifying them. Why do you want a LINQ solution here? What is wrong with the loop you already have?

It is possible to write a LINQ expression that would do what you want, but the expression would either require you to write an explicit `foreach` loop, or materialize the enumeration as an actual object, just to get the expression to execute. The expression would also need to return some value, to preserve the query semantics of LINQ, even though your operation doesn't inherently involve returning a value.

For example, you might write:

```
panel1.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>().Select(
    grid => { grid.Columns.RemoveAt(0); return null; }).ToList();
```

But that code seems fairly ugly to me. It's creating a whole new `List<T>` object that you'll never use, filled with a bunch of `null` values.

If you want to clean up your original code, I'd just do something like the following:

```
foreach (DataGridView grid in panel1.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
{
    grid.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

There, you are using LINQ just for the *query* part of the algorithm, and sticking with conventional imperative semantics for the rest.

Comment: Yes, so. I am learning linq, this is more of an academic exercise than one of practicality. The linq is absolutely unneeded in this case. But I challenge myself and my skills by trying to do it in linq anyway, which helps me to better understand how linq works.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: I see. So, a key point here is that most of the LINQ features involve "deferred execution". That is, calling a LINQ method doesn't actually _do_ anything with your collection, until some code is executed to examine the output of the LINQ expression. That's why in the fully-LINQ example, you have to do something like call `ToList()` in order to make anything happen.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: Deferred execution along with capturing of variables is probably one of the harder things for people new to LINQ to grasp, and failure to do so leads to a lot of confusing, hard-to-fix bugs. So I hope that the exercise here offers some insight as to how deferred execution affects the way that LINQ-based code has to operate.